# Compare two python lists and look for conatains

Tags: python, django, list

```
listA = ['ab', 'bv', 'cd']
listB = ['ab_cd', 'AB_vd', 'ab_ud', 'bV_db', 'bv_de', 'cd_scd']
```

and I have a if condition like

```
for x in listA :
  if x in listB:
    print "Have"
  else:
    print "dun have"
```

But it is always looking for the exact values, but what i need to achieve is a conatains type of search in the list. (Ex: ab actually in listB ('ab_cd', 'AB_vd', 'ab_ud'). Any idea guys? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save some hassle with the **any** function.  It returns **True** if any element of the argument iterable is True, **False** otherwise.  The **and** version of this is called **all**.

```
listA = ['ab', 'bv', 'cd', 'qsz']
listB = ['ab_CD', 'AB_vd', 'ab_ud', 'bV_db', 'bv_de', 'CD_SCD']

for want in listA:
if any(want.lower() in target.lower() for target in listB):
        print "Have", want, "in some listB item"
    else:
        print want, "... we don' got dat one"
```

Output:

```
Have ab in some listB item
Have bv in some listB item
Have cd in some listB item
qsz ... we don' got dat one
```

Comment: Added **lower()** conversion -- credit to @DeveloperXY.  I missed the case-insensitive part of your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
l = ["ListB does have {}".format(a)
      for a in listA for b in listB if a.lower() in b.lower()]

for el in l:
    print el
```

Output:

```
ListB does have ab # 'ab_cd'
ListB does have ab # 'AB_vd'
ListB does have ab # 'ab_ud'
ListB does have bv # 'bV_db'
ListB does have bv # 'bv_de'
ListB does have cd # 'ab_cd'
ListB does have cd # 'cd_scd'
```

Notice the use of `.lower()` so as to match all possible combinations. *(aA-Aa-AA-aa)*

Answer (score 1):

This might help...

```
 for x in listA:
   for y in listB:
     if x.lower() in y.lower():
       print("Have " + x + " in " + y)
```

**OUTPUT**

Have ab in ab_cd

Have ab in AB_vd

Have ab in ab_ud

Have bv in bV_db

Have bv in bv_de

Have cd in ab_cd

Have cd in cd_scd

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this adds over the answer posted by DeveloperXY?  I'm not seeing an advantage.